# Export from Excel to CONTACT type list

Tags: list, excel, contacts

I was able to export from an excel table to sharepoint, however it just creates a normal list.  I want to import data to my CONTACTS LIST in sharepoint via excel, or maybe there is another way to do this.  I have a list of 288 contacts I need to add, and I prefer not to have to manually add each one by one.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

WORKS ONLY IN INTERNET EXPLORER

1. Create a list with preferred types of columns
2. Arrange the excel columns same as SharePoint columns.
3. Copy from Excel to SharePoint list.
   Done!

And I would highly recommend keep the contact column type as "Single line of text" not "Number" type, else you will have comma separated values.